# PyWinAuto detecting multiple different objects as control_type="Pane"

Tags: python, pywinauto

The program I'm trying to automate was written with delphi.

Here a snippet of what I receive when I call "app.window().print_control_identifiers()":

```html
 | Pane - ''    (L242, T512, R835, B588)
   | ['Pane2']
   | child_window(auto_id="919148", control_type="Pane")
   |    | 
   |    | 
   |    | Pane - '5'    (L636, T529, R829, B556)
   |    | ['5', 'Pane4', '5Pane']
   |    | child_window(title="5", auto_id="1247366", control_type="Pane")
   |    | 
   |    | Pane - '4'    (L443, T556, R636, B583)
   |    | ['4Pane', 'Pane5', '4']
   |    | child_window(title="4", auto_id="919154", control_type="Pane")
   |    | 
   |    | Pane - '3'    (L443, T529, R636, B556)
   |    | ['3', 'Pane6', '3Pane']
   |    | child_window(title="3", auto_id="919170", control_type="Pane")
   |    | 
   |    | Pane - '2'    (L250, T556, R443, B583)
   |    | ['2Pane', 'Pane7', '2']
   |    | child_window(title="2", auto_id="853622", control_type="Pane")
   |    | 
   |    | Pane - '1'    (L250, T529, R443, B556)
   |    | ['Pane8', '1Pane', '1']
   |    | child_window(title="1", auto_id="1443906", control_type="Pane")
```

All those Panes should be radio buttons instead.
Being Panes, I can't call methods like ".select()" or ".click()".
The only way I can click those radio buttons is by using the method ".input_click()".
But that doesn't look to be the best approach.
Because I would like to run multiple windows at the same time and doing a "hard click" would make it more difficult. I also have some textEdit objects with the same problem. To manipulate them i would need to make additional steps like clicking the "browse.." button to select a file path.
Is there a way to convert those panes to the true control_type?

Answer (score 0):

With my search, i discovered it's a compatibility problem of the program I was trying to automate with pywinauto.
The only thing that can be done in that case is to content yourself with the hard click method: '.input_click()'.